# Join with other table timestamp and sum of the columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm trying to generate an aggregate table.

Lets say this is my tblA.

```
| type | name | timestap            |
|------|------|---------------------|
| prod | t1   | 2020-06-01 01:00:00 |
| prod | t2   | 2020-06-01 01:00:02 |
| prod | t3   | 2020-06-01 01:00:03 |
| test | t4   | 2020-06-01 02:20:02 |
| test | t5   | 2020-06-01 02:20:03 |
```

and tblB

```
| tid | starttime           | name | subtask | maintask |
|-----|---------------------|------|---------|----------|
| 1   | 2020-06-01 01:10:00 | t1   | 5       | 10       |
| 1   | 2020-06-01 01:10:00 | t1   | 6       | 10       |
| 1   | 2020-06-01 01:10:00 | t1   | 7       | 10       |
| 1   | 2020-06-01 01:10:00 | t1   | 8       | 10       |
| 2   | 2020-06-01 00:01:00 | t1   | 3       | 10       |
| 2   | 2020-05-01 00:02:00 | t1   | 5       | 15       |
| 4   | 2020-06-01 01:00:00 | t2   | 10      | 10       |
| 5   | 2020-06-01 11:00:10 | t2   | 10      | 20       |
| 5   | 2020-06-01 11:00:10 | t2   | 11      | 20       |
| 5   | 2020-06-01 11:00:10 | t2   | 12      | 20       |
```

Now I need to create a report table with the sum of subtask and main task. But there is where condition, we need to pick the tid,subtask, maintask where the starttime is greater than than the tblA's timestamp for each name.Then do the SUM.

#### Expected output:

```
| type | name | sum_of_subtask | sum_of_maintask | diff |
|------|------|----------------|-----------------|------|
| prod | t1   | 26             | 40              | 14   |
| prod | t2   | 33             | 60              | 27   |
```

For t1, the tid would be 1, because its starttime is > tblA.timestamp

for t2, the tid is 5, tblB.starttime > tblA.timestamp

> Also the other condition the rows Im going to pick is the `MAX(tid)
>   where   starttime is > tblA.timestamp`.

Then get the rows and do the sum find the difference between sum_of_subtask,sum_of_maintask  on diff column.

I'm not sure how to write the logic for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need simple `join` and `sum` for aggregation. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ujVMJrv35Z5FJ7kXMQc63F/0).

```
select
  type,
  ta.name,
  sum(subtask) as sum_of_subtask,
  sum(maintask) as sum_of_maintask,
  sum(maintask - subtask) as diff
from tblA ta
join tblB tb
on ta.name = tb.name
where starttime > timestap
group by
  type,
  ta.name;
```

output:

```
| type | name | sum_of_subtask | sum_of_maintask | diff |
| ---- | ---- | -------------- | --------------- | ---- |
| prod | t1   | 26             | 40              | 14   |
| prod | t2   | 33             | 60              | 27   |
```

Comment: But this sum all the column for t1 and t2, I need to sum the rows where the starttime is > than the tblA timestamp.

Comment: @Bhuvanesh updated my answer. please check and also provided you the demo.

Comment: Thank you so much, but one more condition, I need to pick the rows to sum based on timestamp + the tid of the max timestamp, I think I missed that in that question. 
Your query worked, but even I have more than 1 tid with the starttime> the timestamp, then its sum all the rows. Instead just the pick the max(TID) where starttime> the timestamp, that rows needs to be sum. I'll modify the question as well.